# Socket.io show received data from client in html page

Tags: html, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm writing small monitor app. For now it is one direction communication. Client is sending some text to server and server should display recevied text from clients.

My server code (server.js)

```
var serverapp = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(serverapp);
var fs = require('fs');

serverapp.listen(8888);

function handler (req, res) {
    fs.readFile("client.html",
        function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                throw err; 
            }
            res.writeHead(200);
            res.end(data);
        });
}

io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket) {
    socket.on("event_button_clicked", function (data) {
        console.log(data.text);
    });
});
```

and this is client.html

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h1>Client</h1>

<form action="">
<input
    type="text" id="intext">

<input type="button" id="button1"  value="Send"  onclick="btnSend_clicked(this);">
</form>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io.connect(document.location.href);

function btnSend_clicked(button)
{
    socket.emit(
        "event_button_clicked", 
        { text: document.getElementById("intext").value });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

What I want is to have "server" page that will display everything that comes from client. Now it is displayed in console but I don't have idea how to redirect to html and I can't find any example for this kind of problem.